# Erosion and dilation in images

Tags: image-processing, morphological-operations

I don't know if I am posting in the correct place. I wanted to ask about dilation and erosion in bitmaps. I have as a homework to implement in a programming language these morphological operations but I fail in understanding how they work. I know that erosion will shrink an object and dilation will enlarge it.

For example I have
$$A=\matrix{0 &1 &0 &1 & 1\\
0 &1 &0 &1 & 0\\
0 &1 &1 &1 & 0\\
0 &1 &1 &0 & 0\\
0 &1 &1 &1 & 0},\; 
se=\matrix{1 &0 &0\\
1 &1 &0\\
0 &0 &1}$$

What would be the eroded and dilated output and how to compute it step by step?

Comment: Did you read this? http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f18-12508.html

Comment: @leonbloy yes I read it but I used matlab to see if I did it correctly and apparently I did not.

Comment: @J.M. Yes I thought so but then I took a look at the faq and it didn't seem right to post the question there.

Comment: Basically, the implementation of dilation and erosion follow their definition quite close. Some make sure that you really understood these definitions. (By the way: Can you calculate the outcome of your example by hand?) One point which have to be considered in addition to the definition is the boundary treatment. Most often this is done by extending the image $A$ over the boundary as far as needed (e.g. in a symmetric way) and apply erosion and dilation only the "inner pixels" of the  extended image.

Comment: @Dirk I am trying to do it by hand first. I am failing at this point. This is why I am asking for a step by step example.

Comment: Migrating since DSP mods agree with JM that your question is suitable.

Comment: What about a smaller structuring element?

Comment: Structuring elements commonly have odd sizes so that they can be "centered" on each pixel of the image to define the neighbourhood to AND (erosion) or OR (dilatation). So a smaller structuring element would be 1x1. If it contains a zero, the transform is not defined since the structuring element does not define a neighborhood ; if it is contains a one, the transform is the identity.

Comment: I was thinking something like $se=[1 1; 0 0]$. Using `floor((size(se)+1)/2)` (matlab's decision) we take as origin the element (1,1). If I dilate A by se I take $A=[1 1 1 1 1;1 1 1 1 1;1 1 1 1 1; 1 1 1 1 0; 1 1 1 1 1]$ but matlab gives me the answer $A=[0 1 1 1 1;0 1 1 1 1;0 1 1 1 1; 0 1 1 1 0; 0 1 1 1 1]$.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a step-by-step procedure for erosion/dilation by hand:

1. Print out `A` and `se` on two sheets of paper
2. Place the `se` paper on every pixel of the `A` sheet in turn
3. At each position: Take the pixel values of `A` at the respective positions where `se` is 1. For the first top-left position, this would be `0,0,1,1` as I have tried to illustrate here:[image]
4. For an erosion, the result for the current pixel is the logical `AND` of the values you just wrote down. For dilation it is logical `OR`. (Or min/max for grayvalue images)

Note: You will either get a result image that is smaller than `A` or you have to add "padding" pixels to `A` (typically 1 for erosion and 0 for dilation)

Comment: Great answer! How did you create the picture?